# document.ready() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working for selecting the text from a text box to the clipboard with the help of zclip. But the `document.ready()` is not working. It is not even showing the alert.
All required libraries are above the script tag and inside the head section. All the files are at the required positions.

I have even checked the files along with the full URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
alert('hi');
        $("a#copy_initiator").zclip({
            alert('hi');
            path:"js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
           copy:function(){return $("input#copy-box").val();}
        });
    });
</script>


<a id="copy_initiator">Copy Link:</a> <input id="copy-box" type="text"  value="here_is_a_url" onfocus="this.select();">
```

Comment: have you linked jquery before document.ready ?

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the browser console?

Comment: yes I have linked jquery before the document.ready. No errors or warnings in the browser console too.

Comment: The `language` tag has been deprecated - I don't think this will affect execution, but best to remove it anyway.

Comment: @SimonRobb I was going to write not working but now it is working I don't know why, but it just worked. (But Not by removing 'language' tag). Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a syntax problem here:

```
    $("a#copy_initiator").zclip({
        alert('hi');
        path:"js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
       copy:function(){return $("input#copy-box").val();}
    });
```

should be:

```
$("a#copy_initiator").zclip({
    path:"js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy:function(){
        return $("input#copy-box").val();
    }
});
```

And better version:

```
$("#copy_initiator").zclip({
    path:"js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy:function(){
        return $("#copy-box").val();
    }
});
```

Suggestion: use firebug to track these kind of issues.

Comment: It worked now. I have checked in the firebug and that was showing one error now (was not showing that error before). Removed single quotes from the alert(). and applied the changes (better version:) suggested by you. And it is working fine now. Thanks to you and this community.

Answer (score 0):

you say "All required libraries", are you including several libraries ?

If this is the case, it could be possible that they are creating a conflict with jquery "$".

here is a webpage explaining this : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

a test you can do, is going to your console entry in your browser's debugguer and try typing $('div'), or $('p'). If any of the html tags you select are recognize it means the $ is working, otherwise not.

Comment: By all I mean jquery.js and jquery.zclip.js and twitter's widgets.js